# home directories via sshfs and pam_mount

Tags: sshfs, pam-mount

Users' home directories are on a server. They shall be mounted via sshfs on a client when a user logs in, using the password the user provided as credentials. The `pam_mount` system is provided for this. How should it be configured?

Answer (score 0):

These instructions have been tested on Debian 10. Add the following to `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` on the client:

```
<volume fstype="fuse"
path="sshfs#%(USER)@XXX:/home/%(USER)"
mountpoint="/home/%(USER)"
options="nosuid,nodev,noatime,reconnect,nonempty,allow_other,default_permissions,password_stdin"
ssh="0" noroot="0" />
```

Replace `XXX` with the hostname of the server.

`ssh="0"` works in conjunction with the option `password_stdin`. Otherwise, a wrapper `fd0ssh` is used, but it does not work.

`noroot="0"` effects that the mount is carried out as root, not the user. The options `allow_other,default_permissions` make the mounted filesystem blend in with the other filesystems on the client. If the mount is carried out as the user instead, we may run into file permission problems that can make the login fail (Xorg log cannot be written).

`nonempty` makes the mount happen even if the mountpoint is not an empty directory. This option may not be needed for your setup.

`reconnect` looks like a reasonable thing to choose in this situation.

`nosuid,nodev,noatime` are for security and performance; adjust to your needs.

To work around a bug in the sddm login manager (used mainly for KDE), add an option to exclude the user `sddm`, for example `uid="10000-60000`; [see also](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1624268).

At the time of writing, [there is another bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730587) making life hard for sshfs users. It was reported over 5 years ago. My workaround is to completely disable GNOME keyring by:

```
dpkg-divert --divert /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon.bak --rename /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon
```